# Why are the first 2½ minutes unsearchable in the mediaelement.js webplayer?

Tags: javascript, servlets, mediaelement.js

It can play files perfectly fine, but when you try scrolling through the file it jumps from 00:00 to 02:29. You can scroll through the rest of the file as would be expected.

It's a project I've inherited so I'm not much into the specifics of this part of it, but I can't Google it and I can't see anything in the code that would cause it to behave this way. It's implemented in a java servlet so that when you click a button it opens a new servlet containing only the player with the selected file.

As I said, it works just fine, but I cant scroll through the first 2½ minutes, which is a bit irritating.

Comment: Let me just consult my crystal ball.... It say's... post the code in a http://www.sscce.org/ format

Comment: Video, audio file? I think that you should research the problem in the file